# Drawing same shape in the same graphics method c#

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I've been working on a simple graphics project where I can draw shapes using button and edit them (Resize and other stuffs). I've been able to draw different shapes, but my problem is that I cannot draw the same shape again. It only updates the parameter of the previous same shape.

For example, I tried to draw a rectangle and then I want to draw again in a different size, the rectangle changes it size rather than creating a new one.

Here's my code:

**Shape Class**

```
class ShapeClass
{
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
    public Pen color { get; set; }
    public string Shape { get; set; }
 }
```

**Draw Class**

```
class Draw:ShapeClass
    {
    public void DrawRectangle(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(color, new Rectangle(x, y, width, height));
    }
    public void DrawSquare(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(color, new Rectangle(x, y, width, height));
    }
    public void DrawCircle(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(color, new Rectangle(x,y,width,height));
    }
    public void DrawEllipse(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(color, new Rectangle(x, y, width, height));
    }
```

**Paint Events**

```
    public void PaintRect(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //Calls Draw class and sets the parameters of the Shape.
        Draw d = new Draw();
        d.x = rX;
        d.y = rY;
        d.width = rW;
        d.height = rH;
        rC = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
        d.color = rC;
        d.DrawRectangle(e);
    }
    public void PaintSquare(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //Calls Draw class and sets the parameters of the Shape.
        Draw d = new Draw();
        d.x = sX;
        d.y = sY;
        d.width = sW;
        d.height = sH;
        d.color = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
        //d._Rectangle.Add(new Rectangle(sX,sY,sW,sH));
        d.DrawSquare(e);
    }
    public void PaintCircle(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //Calls Draw class and sets the parameters of the Shape.
        Draw d = new Draw();
        d.x = cX;
        d.y = cY;
        d.width = cW;
        d.height = cH;
        d.color = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
        d.DrawCircle(e);
    }
    public void PaintEllipse(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //Calls Draw class and sets the parameters of the Shape.
        Draw d = new Draw();
        d.x = eX;
        d.y = eY;
        d.width = eW;
        d.height = eH;
        d.color = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
        d.DrawEllipse(e);
    }
```

Comment: I think we need to see the definition of `ShapeClass` to see how you define the various location and size parameters.

Comment: Edited the body.

Comment: I'm obviously missing something.  How are you defining `cX`, `cY`, `cW` and `cH`?

Comment: Oh... I think I see the problem.  Let me see if I can answer...

Comment: I defined those variables in Main Form. Thank you

Comment: Every time a `Paint` event is raised, everything you have previously drawn is erased.  If you want multiple shapes drawn then you have to store those shapes in a list at class level and then draw everything in that list on each `Paint` event. You should have one `Paint` event handler that draws every item in the list and then adding a new shape would be a case of adding an item to that list and then forcing a repaint by calling `Refresh`.

Comment: I would also suggest that your classes are badly designed. I'd suggest a class named `Shape` that contains the common members and then a number of derived classes that each represent a single type of shape and know how to draw themselves.  For instance, a `Circle` class would represent a circle.  The `Shape` class would be `abstract` and have an `abstract` `Draw` method and each derived type would override that and provide the implementation required to draw that particular shape.

Comment: Maybe provide me a sample code at least for better reference. I do get what to do, but I'n not quite familiar with the syntax to use.

Comment: The fact that you can't write the correct code seconds after being told what to do is no indication that you can't do it.  Put some thought into it.  Make your best attempt and then, if it doesn't work, update your question with the new code and we can help further.  In short, always do what you can for yourself first and only ask for more help when you actually get stuck.  Assuming you can't do it and asking others to write your code for is not the way to get better at writing code yourself.  Failure is an integral part of learning so the potential for failure is not a reason not to try.

Comment: wise words, thank you. A lot

Comment: I created a list for shapes like what you've said, and I used MessageBox to know if I really stored a shape in there. And it has. My problem is, how do I draw all shapes stored in the List in a PaintEvent? @jmcilhinney

Comment: You create a handler for the `Paint` event of the form or whatever control you want to draw on and then you loop through that list and call the appropriate method on each item.  If you design your classes as I suggested then it's just a case of calling `Draw` on each one. As your classes are currently, you'd probably `switch` on the `Shape` property and call `DrawRectangle` or whatever is appropriate for the current shape.

Comment: Did it. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at your `PaintCircle` event handler for a moment:

```
public void PaintCircle(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    //Calls Draw class and sets the parameters of the Shape.
    Draw d = new Draw();
    d.x = cX;
    d.y = cY;
    d.width = cW;
    d.height = cH;
    d.color = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
    d.DrawCircle(e);
}
```

Fairly straight-forward, but it looks very much like you have a set of values that are defined once on the form: `cX`, `cY`, `cW` and `cH`.  You have similar variables in the other `Paint...` methods.

Almost certain that what's happening is that you are adjusting those variables and redrawing the canvas.  This will generally wipe the existing content and redraw completely, which means that your existing image will be removed and your 'new' shape will be the one that is drawn.

There are a couple of ways to get around this:

1. Make the image persistent

You can create a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` object the right shape for your canvas, do all of your drawing on the `Bitmap` and then update the display.

The down-side of this is that you can't go back and change the existing objects if you want to.  Once you draw on the image it is permanently altered with the new shape.

If you're going this way you should probably give some thought to using multiple `Bitmap` images so you can undo by bringing a prior image from your list.  When you start a draw operation copy the current `Bitmap` and put the copy in your undo list.  To undo, pull the last item from that list and replace your working `Bitmap` with it.  Don't forget to tidy up your undo list to make sure you don't use all of memory.

2. Maintain a list of objects and re-draw the whole list as required

For this you will need to build some more interesting `Shape` classes.

Here's a quick sample...

```
public abstract class Shape
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public Pen LineColor { get; set; } = Pens.Red;
    public Brush FillColor { get; set; } = null;

    public abstract void Draw(Graphics g);
}

public class EllipseShape : Shape
{
    public override void Draw(Graphics g)
    {
        if (FillColor != null)
            g.FillEllipse(FillColor, X, Y, Width, Height);
        g.DrawEllipse(LineColor, X, Y, Width, Height);
    }
}

public class RectangleShape : Shape
{
    public override void Draw(Graphics g)
    {
        if (FillColor != null)
            g.FillRectangle(FillColor, X, Y, Width, Height);
        g.DrawRectangle(LineColor, X, Y, Width, Height);
    }
}
```

... and so on.

On your main form you can add a `List<Shape>` to hold your shapes, then in the `OnPaint` event for the canvas - whatever type of canvas you're using - you do this:

```
private void MainForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var g = e.Graphics;
    foreach (var shape in shapeList)
        shape.Draw(g);
}
```

Comment: Got busy at work and didn't post this until the end of the day.  Hope it was useful anyway :)